# groovy.lang.MissingMethodException : IssueLinkImpl instead of IssueLink

Tags: groovy, jira

In JIRA I try to change the issuetypelink to another linktype with the changeIssueLinkType function.

I get the following error:

`groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.atlassian.jira.issue.link.DefaultIssueLinkManager.changeIssueLinkType() is applicable for argument types: (com.atlassian.jira.issue.link.IssueLinkImpl, com.atlassian.jira.issue.link.IssueLinkTypeImpl, com.atlassian.jira.user.DelegatingApplicationUser) values: [com.atlassian.jira.issue.link.IssueLinkImpl@fffff04e, com.atlassian.jira.issue.link.IssueLinkTypeImpl@ffe53fbd, ...]
Possible solutions: changeIssueLinkType(com.atlassian.jira.issue.link.IssueLink, com.atlassian.jira.issue.link.IssueLinkType, com.atlassian.crowd.embedded.api.User)`

I have no Idea how to fix it...

code:

```
    for (IssueLinkType linktype : issueLinkTypes) 
    {
        String name=linktype.getInward();
        if(name.equals("is parent of"))
        {
            linkTypeNew=linktype;
            break;
        }
    }

UserManager userManager = ComponentAccessor.getUserManager();
ApplicationUser sUser = userManager.getUserByKey("Username");

Collection<IssueLink> allIssueLinks =    ComponentAccessor.getIssueLinkManager().getIssueLinks(linkID);

for (Iterator<IssueLink> outIterator = allIssueLinks.iterator();    outIterator.hasNext();) {
         IssueLink issueLink = (IssueLink) outIterator.next();

        ComponentAccessor.getIssueLinkManager().changeIssueLinkType(issueLink,     linkTypeNew, sUser);
      }
```

Would be great if someone could help me:-/

Answer (score 0):

Obviously your `sUser` variable is of wrong type. The method `changeIssueLinkType()` expects a user of type `com.atlassian.crowd.embedded.api.User` whereas you pass a user of type `com.atlassian.jira.user.DelegatingApplicationUser`.

I'm not a JIRA API expert, but as a quick fix I'd suggest the following:

```
import com.atlassian.crowd.embedded.api.User


ApplicationUser sUser = userManager.getUserByKey("Username")
User user = sUser as User // this line might fail!
....
ComponentAccessor.issueLinkManager.changeIssueLinkType issueLink, linkTypeNew, user
```

If the line fails, you have to create an instance of `User` on your own

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing in the `sUser` object (it implements `ApplicationUser`, which is not compatible with `User`), you should call `sUser.getDirectoryUser()` and supply that result to your method call in order to get the correct user object type. You should also change the explicit `ApplicationUser sUser = ...` initialization to just `def sUser = ...`.

This works here because you have a `DelegatingApplicationUser` object which supports the `getDirectoryUser` method. If you have a different type of `ApplicationUser` implementation, which does not necessarily support that method, you would need to use a utility method to convert it. You can find more information on `User` vs `ApplicationUser` [in Atlassian's documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/latest-updates/developer-changes-for-older-jira-versions/preparing-for-jira-6-0/renamable-users-in-jira-6-0).